# PCA on the targets with sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am doing multiple target regression, so I want to predict several numbers simultaneously. The numbers are highly correlated, so I think predicting their PC's is a more sensible approach.

Using sklearn's Pipeline is great for daisy-chaining together the MinMaxScaler, PCA, and the regressor I want to use; and then allowing me to call that Pipeline to make predictions.

However, does that Pipeline apply PCA to the inputs only? Is it possible to use the same strategy, but also have it perform PCA on the outputs that I want to predict too?

Comment: Just to clarify the question, you are asking if you can use the same PCA from the same Pipeline you described (MinMaxScaler, PCA, and regressor) on the output of the regressor?

Comment: How are you planning to apply your predictor at test time (how will you evaluate correctness on the original un-PCA'd targets)? Note that if you're predicting in the reduced dimension space, you can't, in general, transform your results back to the original dimensionality of the output space. This won't make much sense unless you're doing some sort of intermediate supervision, in which the dimensionality reduced output space serves as input to later layers of predictors.

Comment: @eqzx What do you mean 'you can't transform back to the original dimensionality of the output space'? You can always inverse_transform the PCA transformation, once obtained the reduced output.

Comment: @Michael yes, I meant they won't be able to obtain perfect reconstruction if the PCA'd targets they're predicting aren't in the set of original data that was PCA'd (inverse_transform yields exact results for the original data set, and interpolates for dimensionality-reduced points corresponding to points not in the original data set). e.g. original feature dimensionality of targets Y is 100, PCA reduces to 2, any predicted target of dimensionality 2 won't be exactly reconstructed to 100 dimensional point after inverse_transform unless the predicted point is in the target training set

Answer (score 2):

No, it is possible to use steps in pipeline only for transforming X argument. You may create additional pipeline for y, where all steps should be transformers, and then feed result of this pipeline as y to a classifier.